# Why my code cause SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, warnings

I tried below two ways

```
df_weather = pd.read_sql_table('cityweathers', self.engine)

def process_city_weather(df_weather):
    df_weather.loc[:, "date_create"] = pd.to_datetime(df_weather[["year", "month","day"]])
    # df_weather.loc[:, "update"] = pd.to_datetime(df_weather.time_create, unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai').dt.tz_localize(None)
    df_weather = df_weather.drop_duplicates(['date_create'], keep='last')

    # method 1
    df_weather.loc[:, 'fineday'] = df_weather.weather.apply(lambda x: '雨' not in x).astype(int)
    # method 2
    df_weather['fineday'] = df_weather.weather.apply(lambda x: '雨' not in x).astype(int)
```

Both not work ,
I turned on `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = 'raise'` to catch where the warnings come from. Got error on first way:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "map_reduce.py", line 743, in <module>
    main()
  File "map_reduce.py", line 738, in main
    delayed(purchase_count_forecaster)(order_path, stock_path) for order_path, stock_path in read_map_by_store_id()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 983, in __call__
    if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 825, in dispatch_one_batch
    self._dispatch(tasks)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 782, in _dispatch
    job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 182, in apply_async
    result = ImmediateResult(func)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\_parallel_backends.py", line 545, in __init__
    self.results = batch()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 261, in __call__
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py", line 261, in <listcomp>
    for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
  File "map_reduce.py", line 391, in purchase_count_forecaster
    df_weather = process_city_weather(df_weather)
  File "e:\pp\sales-forecast\mlc\preprocess\weather.py", line 14, in process_city_weather
    df_weather['fineday'] = df_weather.weather.apply(lambda x: '雨' not in x).astype(int)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3119, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3201, in _set_item
    self._check_setitem_copy()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2712, in _check_setitem_copy
    raise com.SettingWithCopyError(t)
pandas.core.common.SettingWithCopyError:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

I have seen [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandasW) , but it doesn't cover my case

### **UPDATE**

The function entry is like below

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def main():
    process_num = 1 if DEBUG else 4
    Parallel(n_jobs=process_num)(
        delayed(purchase_count_forecaster)(order_path, stock_path) for order_path, stock_path in read_map_by_store_id()
    )

def purchase_count_forecaster(order_path, stock_path):
    hdfs = HdfsClient(host=HDFS_HOST, port=HDFS_PORT)
    db = Database(DB_URL)

    df_weather = db.read_weathers() # pd.read_sql_table here
    df_weather = process_city_weather(df_weather)

    # ....
```

### Env:

```
In [2]: pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.6.5.final.0
python-bits: 64
OS: Windows
OS-release: 10
machine: AMD64
processor: Intel64 Family 6 Model 45 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None
LOCALE: None.None

pandas: 0.23.4
pytest: 3.5.1
pip: 18.1
setuptools: 39.1.0
Cython: 0.28.2
numpy: 1.14.3
scipy: 1.1.0
pyarrow: 0.11.0
xarray: None
IPython: 6.4.0
sphinx: 1.7.4
patsy: 0.5.0
dateutil: 2.7.3
pytz: 2018.4
blosc: None
bottleneck: 1.2.1
tables: 3.4.3
numexpr: 2.6.5
feather: None
matplotlib: 2.2.2
openpyxl: 2.5.3
xlrd: 1.1.0
xlwt: 1.3.0
xlsxwriter: 1.0.4
lxml: 4.2.1
bs4: 4.6.0
html5lib: 1.0.1
sqlalchemy: 1.2.7
pymysql: None
psycopg2: None
jinja2: 2.10
s3fs: None
fastparquet: None
pandas_gbq: None
pandas_datareader: None
```

Comment: @jezrael It read from mysqldb, code:  `df_weather = pd.read_sql_table('cityweathers', self.engine)
`  . Why need copy here?

Comment: I think need `df_weather = df_weather.drop_duplicates(['date_create'], keep='last').copy()`, can you test it?

Comment: @jezrael  You are right . At first I tried `df_weather.loc[:, 'fineday'] = df_weather.copy().weather.apply(lambda x: '雨' not in x).astype(int)` still get this warning. But `df_weather = df_weather.drop_duplicates(['date_create'], keep='last').copy()`  this does solve the warning. Could you mind explain the reason ?

Comment: One idea, how is call function `process_city_weather` ? Something like `df_weather = process_city_weather(df_weather)` ? Or different?

Comment: My main problem I cannot simulate your problem, what is your pandas version?

Comment: All seems perfectly, no idea what is problem. Maybe Parallel create some temporary variables, but I have no experience with module `Parallel`, so it is guessing only. If possible, can you test function without parallel?

Comment: @jezrael Test without error, I think need submit an issue to pandas .

Comment: Is this maybe connected to: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20856? You can check if `weather_df` is a copy on line 4 in your `process_city_weather` function by doing: `weather_df.is_copy`.